# How to check if the mouse control is inside VM console c#?

Tags: c#, .net, virtual-machine, vmware

Suppose i have opened a vm console(EXSI or vcloud) in a browser.

I have a requirement to check whether the mouse pointer is inside the vm console or in the physical machine.

Is there a way in which i can find out where the mouse control is ?
what would be the difference in the properties of a mouse control when it is captured inside a vm console and in physical machine ?

Thanks

Comment: Alas, I don't think "mouse control" works this way.  Mouse events are captured in the UI application window of whatever application the mouse pointer is hovering over, so you would have to have hooks in the VM console's mouse events to detect this.

Comment: @Robert Harvey : I want to verify the mouse location from the physical machine. Even if i set a hook inside VM console's window, how can i get to know the mouse control is inside the VM console.?

Comment: Because you will start receiving mouse events from the VM console.  Naturally, you would need a communication channel from the VM console to the physical machine.  As I said, I don't think mouse control works the way you described.  As far as I know, the mouse control's properties don't change in any way when you move focus from the local machine to a remote one.  What you're really looking for is a way to detect *focus.*